# AngularJS: JSONP request to a service without a callback. Why does this work?

Tags: php, ajax, angularjs

Using AngularJS, I am sending a JSONP request to a server, which does not return anything.  The success callback still gets executed.  Does anyone know why?  Does it just add an empty script to the page?

I have this on the frontend:

```
$scope.send = function(forms){
    $http.jsonp('http://myserver.com/write.php?formsJSON='+JSON.stringify(forms)).success(alert('Saved on server'));
                }
```

And this backend:

```
<?php
if (!(isset($_GET['formsJSON']))) {
    exit("formsJSON not set, exiting...");
}
$file = 'people.txt';
file_put_contents($file, $_GET['formsJSON']);
?>
```

Comment: What is the question, and where is the back-end that you say you have but I do not see?

Comment: I just finished writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`alert('Saved on server')` runs right away. You need to wrap it with a function that will be executed later.

```
.success( function(response){ alert('Saved on server'); } );
```

Comment: Still, it adds and empty script tag to the page, right?